# In R Shiny, how to update only one value in a user input matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, shiny, shiny-reactivity

In the below MWE code, I'm trying to get any user inputs in Matrix 1 to be reactively reflected in Matrix 2 upper right hand corner only ([1,2)] while preserving all other values previously input into Matrix 2. The three images at bottom explain the issue: not all values are accurately preserved. Is preservation of the previous inputs except Matrix 2 [1,2] possible? How can this be done?

I've fiddled with matrix indices and am hitting a wall.

Note the warning posted in R Studio Console as shown in the final image.

This is "almost MWE", but the UDF `interpol()` for extra/interpolation can be safely ignored making the code simple.

MWE code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

interpol <- function(a, b) { # [a] = modeled periods, [b] = matrix inputs
  c <- b
  c[,1][c[,1] > a] <- a
  d <- diff(c[,1, drop = FALSE])
  d[d <= 0] <- NA
  d <- c(1,d)
  c <- cbind(c,d)
  c <- na.omit(c)
  c <- c[,-c(3),drop=FALSE]
  e <- rep(NA, a)
  e[c[,1]] <- c[,2]
  e[seq_len(min(c[,1])-1)] <- e[min(c[,1])]
  if(max(c[,1]) < a){e[seq(max(c[,1]) + 1, a, 1)] <- 0}
  e <- approx(seq_along(e)[!is.na(e)], e[!is.na(e)], seq_along(e))$y # Interpolates
  return(e)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput('periods', 'Modeled periods (X):', min=1, max=10, value=10),
  
  h5(strong("Matrix 1:")), 
  matrixInput("matrix1", 
              value = matrix(c(5), nrow = 1, ncol = 1, dimnames = list("Base rate (Y)",NULL)),
              rows =  list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
              cols =  list(names = FALSE),
              class = "numeric"),
  
  h5(strong("Matrix 2:")), 
  matrixInput("matrix2",
              value = matrix(c(10,5), nrow = 1, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y"))),
              rows = list(extend = TRUE, names = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
              class = "numeric"),
  
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent(input$periods,{
    updateMatrixInput(
      session, 
      inputId = "matrix2", 
      value = matrix(c(input$periods,input$matrix2[1,2]), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y")))
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix1, {
    updateMatrixInput(
      session, 
      inputId = "matrix2",
      value = matrix(c(input$matrix2[,1],input$matrix1[,1]), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y")))
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix2, { 
    if(any(rownames(input$matrix2) == "")){
      tmpMatrix <- input$matrix2
      rownames(tmpMatrix) <- paste("Row", seq_len(nrow(input$matrix2)))
      isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix2", value = tmpMatrix))
      }
    input$matrix2
    })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$matrix2)
    plot(interpol(input$periods, input$matrix2))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this was easy. In the `observeEvent` for matrix1, I simply disassembled the two column inputs for matrix2 (into objects `col1` and `col2`), substituted the matrix1 value into the correct position in the vector of combined matrix2 column inputs (`joinCol`), and updated matrix2 using the `updateMatrixInput` function, as shown below:

```
observeEvent(input$matrix1, {
  
    col1 <- input$matrix2[,1]
    col2 <- input$matrix2[,2]
    joinCol <- c(col1,col2)
    joinCol[length(input$matrix2)/2+1] <- input$matrix1[,1]
    
    updateMatrixInput(
      session, 
      inputId = "matrix2",
      value = matrix(joinCol,
                     ncol = 2, 
                     dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y")))
    )
  })
```